# Source has 5 element(s) but target allows only 0

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript, testing, types

The typescript show this error:

```
Source has 5 element(s) but target allows only 0
```

Test.ts

```
await Map.createPoint("New York",[[323, 232],
      [123, 233],
      [221, 455],
      [321, 212],
      [122, 253]]);
```

Map.ts

```
class Map{
  async createGeofencesTest(city:string,points:[]): Promise<void> {
    await Admin.setGeofenceCity(city); 
    await Admin.Points(points);
    return;
  }
}
```

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: `points:[]` <- what does this declaration mean?

Comment: @[] - type array

Comment: `[]` is an array with 0 elements. Do you mean `number[][]` or `[number, number][]`?

Answer (score 2):

The type `[]` is an array with 0 elements. You need either `number[][]` or `[number, number][]`.

`number[][]` is an array of arrays of numbers.

`[number, number][]` is an array of `[number, number]`. `[number, number]` is an array with exactly two numbers.